# Reactive models

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Reactive View components (React, Angular, Vue, etc) revolutionized interface programming by eliminating the need to keep the view up to date with props/state. But as far as I know an analogous Model pattern has not been implemented/popularized (if Redux solves this problem, it's unclear to me how it can do so with classes).

The main area I'm running into a need for this (across many applications) is when some kind of constraining is involved. Some child/related model needs to be constrained when it is created, when it is updated, when the parent is updated, or when siblings are updated.

It could be done something like the following (just threw this together quickly to illustrate), but this isn't very efficient at scale because it's not selective (i.e. React only rerenders components that change).

Are there any implementations of this kind of data structure, or is this something I have to roll myself?

```
class ReactiveModel {
  setState(newState) {
    this.state = newState;

    this.updateChildren();
  }

  setProps(newProps) {
    this.props = newProps;

    this.updateChildren();
  }

  updateChildren() {
    var childrenSpecification = this.renderChildren();

    //for each child
      //create a new instance if one doesn't exist
      //update props if any need to be updated
        //updating props or state on a child triggers updateChildren on it so updating bubbles down
  }
}

class Box extends ReactiveModel {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      boxObjects: this.props.boxObjectsFromApi //just plain data - "Object" instances, not "Box" instances
    }
  }

  addBox(boxObject) {
    this.setState({boxObjects: [...this.state.boxObjects, boxObject]}); //should call updateChildren
  }

  renderChildren() {
    return {
      boxes: this.state.boxObjects.map(({width}) => {
        return {
          class: Box,
          props: {
            width: Math.min(this.props.width, width) //constrain child width to be inside parent width
          }
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: define constrain

Comment: by constrain do you mean filter? If so you can put filters in getters that conditionally trigger, assuming your data is coming from a Redux or Vuex store.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I mean make sure a value meets some parameters/constraints. i.e. make sure each child's "width" property is between 10 and (the parent's width - 1)

Comment: That's the responsibility of the component. If you want some sort of generic AOP for components you'd probably want to consider some sort of declarative HOC, looks like there's react-aop already, but I haven't looked at it at all. If you want this to live at the store level (e.g., Redux) you could do something at the store level... but data integrity checks should have already happened before it gets to the store or leaves the user's hand, and again on the server side (always the source of truth).

Comment: @maxhud so why not add that logic into a `onCreated` or similar lifecycle method

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think I'm being understood unfortunately. My question is as simple as "Is there something like React Components for Model implementations", where components in React render methods are analogous to related models.

Comment: Honestly have no clue what you are trying to explain. If you don't want to show a component because its `width` property is too large, you would use conditional rendering.

Comment: Can you provide a use case?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I want the underlying representation of a view (the data or Model that the view is rendering) to always have a value that is within a specified range. That specified range may change because of complex relationships outside the model (i.e it's parent or child changes).

Comment: @DaveNewton ideally responsibility is not confined to the model itself, because siblings of the model or parents of the model might affect it, and the model should know as little as possible about its parents/siblings. In react, it's the responsibility of the parent component to keep child components up to date with each other.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I've got 3d boxes that have a size and have boxes inside them. All boxes have sizes and positions. When the parent box downsizes, child boxes that end up outside of it should be downsized to fit. when sibling boxes resize, other siblings should downsize to fit. I want to implement the constraining of the box sizes in one place, and then have it happen any time any of the boxes get created/changed. This is just one of 100 different scenarios where I have had trouble with this. I want a generalized solution - obviously there is a relatively common solution to that one problem

Comment: @maxhud in that case you just need a state store. So you would have a parent component that gets its data from the state store, and passes that data down as props to its children. So when data changes in one child component, every other child will know about it.

Comment: @maxhud to add to that, you could always use event emitters to update state of a component. When one component changes, it fires an event that updates other components. I think you're making it more complicated than what it needs to be.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine right - then I would just use redux. But I want to use object-oriented patterns in some form, like react does - because it is organizationally far superior. What you're suggesting is the model equivalent of using redux with jquery rather than just using react without redux. I do currently use event emitters and they have to be attached/removed and that is brittle, just as adding and removing elements with jquery is brittle while adding/removing elements with react is 100% reliable

Comment: This is the closes thing I've found, but it's pretty verbose compared to using a class with "this": https://medium.com/@ustunozgur/object-oriented-functional-programming-or-how-can-you-use-classes-as-redux-reducers-23462a5cae85

Comment: Idk man, I think you are trying to use react in a way it wasn't meant to be used. Not to say that there aren't good solutions to your problem. I don't see how using redux and event emitters makes it a non object oriented pattern. It doesn't have to be as complex as you make it seem.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine check my updated question - does that make it more clear what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @DaveNewton check my updated question - does that make it more clear what I'm trying to do?

Comment: OOP isn't inherently "organizationally superior". There's nothing that says your state can't be a tree of objects that react to parental changes-the store doesn't care at all what's in it-so build your OO models, put them in the store, and your components won't care at all what the underlying data source is. All they need to know is the shape of the properties they consume.